# integral f(-x) from -a to a equal to integral f(x) from -a to a

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions

Can someone help with a short algebraic proof that $\int_{-a}^ag(x)=\int_{-a}^ag(-x)$
From making a sketch this seems to be correct and you could argue from the graph that it would be correct as the function is mirrored in the y-axis. However, I would like to have a short argument that goes better on paper and is more precise. If someone knows where to find an example I would appreciate it a lot.

If someone has another idea the problem arises from proving $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cdot \exp({inx})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(-x)\cdot \exp{(in(-x))}$

Where $i$ is the imaginary number, $n$ is an integer and $f(x)$ is a piecewise differentiable $2\pi$ periodic function. This is part of a proof in Fourier analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=-x$, then:
$$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) \mathrm{d}x=\int_{a}^{-a} f(-u)\mathrm{d}(-u)=-\int_a^{-a}f(-u)\mathrm{d}u$$
Can you continue?

Every function can be decomposed into the sum of an odd and an even function:
$$f(x)=f_o(x)+f_e(x)$$
Where
$$f_e(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$$
and
$$f_o(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$$
So
$$\int_{-a}^a f(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-a}^af_o(x)\mathrm{d}x+\int_{-a}^af_e(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
$$\int_{-a}^a f(-x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-a}^af_o(-x)\mathrm{d}x+\int_{-a}^af_e(-x)\mathrm{d}x$$
The integral of an odd function on a symmetric interval is $0$, so we are left with
$$\int_{-a}^a f(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-a}^af_e(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
$$\int_{-a}^a f(-x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-a}^af_e(-x)\mathrm{d}x$$
But $f_e$ is even, so $f_e(x)=f_e(-x)$:
$$\int_{-a}^a f(-x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-a}^af_e(-x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-a}^af_e(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-a}^a f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: $=-(-\int_{-a}^af(-u)du=\int_{-a}^af(-u)du$

Which is just a change of variable from calling it x...?

Comment: @AndreasP yes! I've just came up with another solution. Do you want me to add it to the answer?

Comment: Great! You are very much welcome to add all the solutions you come up with :-)

Comment: @AndreasP I've added it. Note that the proof of the "$\int_{-a}^{a}f_o=0$ is really similar to the first proof, but I think it's easier to see that it's true (or at least for me). Also, this odd-even decomposition can be useful sometimes.

Comment: That is a great proof. And it only gets better since we have proved every aspect you use in our course! Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @AndreasP I'm glad I could help.